# Custom Registration process to onboard other users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am building a Laravel webapp, where I need to implement a custom registration process. Now I am not sure, whether I can/should use the built-in Authentication features from Laravel or not.

I have three types of users:

1. Admin users: My colleagues in my company who talk to clients, onboard them, etc.
2. Clients: Users who create certain tasks, that need to be done. They could more or less use a "standard registration" process
3. Service Providers: Users who fulfill tasks for clients. They need to be onboarded by our company. So our admin users would create their user profile and send them an invitation link.

Especially the Service Providers are giving me a headache. Is this kind of custom registration flow possible in Laravel or do I have to build my own custom athentication to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question. I have implemented Laravel Authentication with custom features before, I would recommend you to take the following steps:

- Install Laravel Authentication.
- Update users table with a column name type that will distinguish between users.
- Create middleware for each user. Middleware helps you which user can access or perform which tasks.

If you have different elements for each user then you can also implement policies or gates to show specific elements on your blade template according to user type.

I would not recommend creating custom Authentication for this scenario, as you have to implement proper session handling throttling, forgot password, verify the process along with emails and notifications. which is built-in by default in Laravel.

If you want to edit the register and login function you can do that. ;)